# How should I use git submodules to share code between Heroku apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have a few Rails 3 apps deployed to Heroku that need to share some business logic. Apparently, although Heroku's Bundler support is pretty solid, it can't yet pull from a private Github repo. So instead I'm building a couple of gems, vendoring them into each app, checking them into git, and pushing them up with the rest of my code.

This has worked alright, but every time I want to change something in these shared gems I have to go to each app, gem unpack to the right directory, git add/git remove all the files that have changed, and so on, and it's becoming a bit of a pain. I may also want to set up different branches of my business logic, and having different applications follow different branches, but I don't know how I'd accomplish that by vendoring.

It looks like git submodules were invented for this kind of situation, but the last time I tried submodules I just found them horribly confusing. I suppose that's what I'd need to do, but the code snippet that Heroku gives as an example at that link is also pretty confusing.

So, my questions:

1. Are submodules what I want to use here?
2. What's the simplest possible git workflow I'd need in order to do what I'm describing?

I'm not a beginner with git, but I'm not quite intermediate either, and I want to start with a simple set of steps I can use to learn from. I'd need to track a local git repository from within my vendor/gems directory, pull in updates from that repository regularly, and do so in such a way that Heroku/Bundler doesn't throw a fit when I try to push the entire app to production.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find apenwarr’s [*git subtree*](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt) command helpful. It provides a nice wrapper around [Git’s subtree merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) functionality.

Add a new subtree:

```
git subtree add --prefix=vendor/gems/shiny remote-or-url-to-shiny-gem branch
```

Pull new commits into the subtree:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=vendor/gems/shiny remote-or-url-to-shiny-gem branch
```

You might also like the `--squash` option if you do not want to incorporate the history.

You can also use *git subtree* to extract local commits that change the subtree so that they can be pushed to the subtree’s source repository (the *split* and *push* sub-commands).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git-subtree technique

http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html

Answer (score 0):

As for me, git-subtree was a non sufficient. It required too much tweaking and digging and the result had some annoying flaws and made it look like a bandage. BTW The mentioned [apenwarr’s git subtree](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt) was last updated two years ago (as to Apr12...) and if git subtree is chosen then i recommend using [helmo's fork](https://github.com/helmo/git-subtree) (or alikes).

I would deifintly recommend using git submodules. Sure, its has some flaws too, but most of them are better handled in later version of git, and you could add some [hooks](https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils) and [scripts](http://cemerick.com/2009/09/28/working-with-git-submodules-recursively/) to make it usable by git newbies. Plus, its far more widely used.

Regarding Heroku, [it is now supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules). If you need private repositories,  Create a user and use its credentials for this purpose and use this format for the repository location:
https://username:password@github.com/user/repo.git
More, For Ruby apps, you can alternately do this with Bundler's :git option.

HTH